# Firefox problems

Tags: firefox

I am running Ubuntu 14.04, I don't know what I did but Firefox will not open from the icon, I have to type in the terminal for it to open. I have tried Suds Firefox -P and everything else that I have seen posted on this forum and non of it works. any ideas on how I can fix this Firefox problem?

Answer (score 0):

Install menu editor from terminal...

`sudo apt-get install alacarte`

from terminal open the menu editor...

`alacarte &`

Select Internet from the left side, and locate Firefox from the right side and select it. Click on the button marked "Properties". In the "Launcher Properties" dialog box that opens makes sure that the entry within the text field labelled "Command" has the following within it (If not replace it)...

`firefox %u`

Click close until all dialog boxes are closed. Firefox should be working properly now.

If this doesn't work try this at the terminal...

`sudo apt-get install firefox --reinstall`

Comment: still did not work, the command had firefox %u and i even replaced it just to make sure

Comment: try what in the terminal?

Comment: sudo apt-get install firefox --reinstall

Comment: sampson@sampson-Inspiron-7720:~$ sudo apt-get install firefox --reinstall –
[sudo] password for sampson: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file 'linux.dell.com.sources.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'linux.dell.com.sources.lis' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package –
sampson@sampson-Inspiron-7720:~$ 

this is what i got

Comment: What happens when you try firefox?

Comment: Hold it your package sources are messed up. One moment.

Comment: when i click on the icon i get the "your profile is missing" i have made multiple profiles

Comment: sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linux.dell.com.sources.lis /etc/apt/source.list.d/linux.dell.com.sources.list then reboot and try what I said the last time. Thanks!

Comment: sampson@sampson-Inspiron-7720:~$ sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/linux.dell.com.sources.lis /etc/apt/source.list.d/linux.dell.com.sources.list 
[sudo] password for sampson: 
mv: cannot move ‘/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linux.dell.com.sources.lis’ to ‘/etc/apt/source.list.d/linux.dell.com.sources.list’: No such file or directory
sampson@sampson-Inspiron-7720:~$ 
 this is what i got when i typed it in

Comment: ls /etc/apt/ and tell me what you get.

Comment: I believe you have more of a problem than just firefox not starting up from its associated icon. Firefox is just a symptom of a much bigger problem here.

Comment: sampson@sampson-Inspiron-7720:~$ ls /etc/apt/
apt.conf.d     sources.list    sources.list.save  trusted.gpg   trusted.gpg.d
preferences.d  sources.list.d  trustdb.gpg        trusted.gpg~
 this is what i get from ls/etc/apt/ and i havent had any problems besides firefox

Comment: so if it is a bigger problem how do i go about fixing it